# CSS3 Animation / Fade

Tags: css

Good afternoon, I'm trying to auto fade after 3 seconds one image into another. once the second image is 100% opacity I need it to stay and not loop. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: use javascript function SetTimeout

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/ySJY9/2)**

**CSS:**

```
/*Add required verdon prefixes*/
img{   
    width:300px; height:300px;
    display:block;

    /* Background in place of `src` attribute*/
    background:url("http://placehold.it/200x200");

    opacity:0;

    /*`fade` = name; `3s` = duration; `1` - number of times animation takes place*/
    -webkit-animation:fade 3s 1;  
    -moz-animation:fade 3s 1;  

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade{
    to{
        opacity:1;
        background:url("http://placehold.it/250x200");
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes fade{
    to{
        opacity:1;
        background:url("http://placehold.it/250x200");
    }
}
```

Important property used:

**[`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/animation-fill-mode)** - "The animation-fill-mode CSS property specifies how a CSS animation should apply styles to its target before and after it is executing."
Setting `forwards` as a value makes the final properties acquired stay in the element.